# CakePHP 4, AWS Elasticsearch 7 - The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, cakephp, elastica

So I'm running CakePHP 4 on an EC2 instance, AWS ES 7 and I've setup the ElasticSearch plugin in CakePHP.

```
composer require cakephp/elastic-search "^3.0"
```

I've added the elastic datasource connection in config/app.php

```
'elastic' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\ElasticSearch\Datasource\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\ElasticSearch\Datasource\Connection',
            'host' => 'search-DOMAIN.REGION.es.amazonaws.com',
            'port' => 443,
            'transport' => "AwsAuthV4",
            'aws_access_key_id' => "KEY",
            'aws_secret_access_key' => "SECRET",
            'aws_region' => "REGION",
            'ssl' => 'true',
        ],
```

.. and I've activated the plugin

```
use Cake\ElasticSearch\Plugin as ElasticSearchPlugin;

class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    public function bootstrap()
    {
        $this->addPlugin(ElasticSearchPlugin::class);
```

I've manually added 1 index record to ES via curl from the EC2 instance. So I know the communication between EC2 and ES works.

```
curl -XPUT -u 'KEY:SECRET' 'https://search-DOMAIN.REGION.es.amazonaws.com/movies?pretty' -d '{"director": "Burton, Tim", "genre": ["Comedy","Sci-Fi"], "year": 1996, "actor": ["Jack Nicholson","Pierce Brosnan","Sarah Jessica Parker"], "title": "Mars Attacks!"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I also managed to search for this record via curl without any problems.

In the AppController.php I tried this simple search just to see if the plugin works and for the life of me, I can't get it to work.

```
# /src/Controller/AppController.php
...
use Cake\ElasticSearch\IndexRegistry;

class AppController extends Controller
{

    public function initialize(): void
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadModel('movies', 'Elastic');
        $query = $this->movies->find('all');
        $results = $query->toArray();
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Client error: POST
> https://search-DOMAIN.REGION.es.amazonaws.com/movies/movies/_search
> resulted in a 403 Forbidden response: {"message":"The security token
> included in the request is invalid."}
> Elastica\Exception\Connection\GuzzleException

Seems like the plugin adds the 'Index' name twice for some reason. I looked everywhere for a setting that I might have missed. If I copy and paste the above URL and remove the duplicate Index from the URL in a browser it works fine.

```
https://search-DOMAIN.REGION.es.amazonaws.com/movies/_search
```

Am I missing something here?

I've even tried this method, and I get the same problem with duplicated index values in the url.

```
$Movies = IndexRegistry::get('movies');
$query = $Movies->find('all');
$results = $query->toArray();
```

I've tried a new/clean CakePHP instance and I get the same problem? Is there something wrong with the plugin? Is there a better approach to communicate with ES via CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the plugin and Elasticsearch, but as far as I understand, one of the `movies` is the index name, and one of them is the type name, where the type name - at least according to the documentation - should be singular, ie the path would instead be expected to look like:

```
/movies/movie/_search
```

> Furthermore, Index classes assume that the type mapping has the singular name of the index. For example the `articles` index has a type mapping of `article`.

**https://book.cakephp.org/elasticsearch/3/en/3-0-upgrade-guide.html#types-renamed-to-indexes**

Whether that would be the correct path with respect to what is supported by the used Elasticsearch version, that might be a different question.

You may want to open an issue over [**at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/elastic-search/issues).

Comment: Yeah I think you got a point that this plugin might not support ES 7.x as index 'types' are depricated since ES 7.x. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html

I don't specify the URL structure at all, the plugin handles that.

Comment: @Skobbejak The path is generated by  `ruflin/elastica` AFAICT. ES 7.x isn't supported yet, but according to the version map it will be in the upcoming 4.x version of the plugin. If you're adventurous, try `dev-master` of the plugin.